# Using TikZ limits with high precision results in `pgfplots: the current plot has no coordinates (or all have been filtered away)` error

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I attempt to use high precision values for `xmin` and `xmax` in TikZ, all elements appear to be filtered away. Specifically,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0.9030, xmax=0.9129,
]
\addplot [black]
table {%
0.9035 19.8014
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

compiles correctly. But adding `9000` to each x value, changing the code to:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=9100.9030, xmax=9100.9129,
]
\addplot [black]
table {%
9100.9035 19.8014
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

results in an error:

```
Warning:(1) pgfplots: the current plot has no coordinates (or all have been filtered away)
```

This suggests that TikZ cannot handle limit values with the precision required by values such as `xmin=9100.9030` and `xmax=9100.9129`.

Is there a way I can allow the plot to have limits with such precision? If not, are there suggested workarounds?

Comment: I assume that you use pgfplots, right? I recommend to add an example of your actual use case including the expected output in order to better be able to propose a workaround.

Comment: @dr-manuel-kuehner, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G-ZubcKvLdDHb0YsB6PbQMNHZJdtKlGC/view?usp=sharing) is my real case and [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m773WVItOm7PfC-yHQP5mQs-tsphHYwb/view?usp=sharing) is what it should eventually look close to. I'm using `tikzplotlib` to generate the tikz files. The question bug will not be the only bug currently in the example file, but it's the current roadblock. I intend to generate many figures of a similar nature, and so I am hoping to find a solution that it not data dependent.

Comment: Maybe you can scale the data, e. g. multiplied by ten. The tick labels can be set manually to the correct value. But this is maybe not feasible for many figures.